# browser Unique id asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I need to navigate between two Websites.

Login from one site and pass the session to another website(its highly impossible).

So I need to identify the browser (not like `Request.browser.browser or Request.browser.Id`) and maintain the identification between the two web Applications.

Is that possible? If it is possible how do I identify the browser?

Comment: If you make a custom session id you can pass it around. This would be easier than trying to identify browsers by ids. (Not quite sure what end this leads to)

Answer (score 3):

I think you are going wrong way, you should use [SSO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on) for this kind of problem

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27576/Single-Sign-on-in-ASP-NET-and-Other-Platforms) is good article for implementing with asp.net

Answer (score 0):

Please go through the following URL's for reference

http://www.asp101.com/articles/jayram/sharestate/default.asp

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Sharing_session_state.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/toddca/archive/2007/01/25/sharing-asp-net-session-state-across-applications.aspx

where as Sign Sign On is still the best solution.